# Search for a value in the arrays and get the array name

Tags: java, android, arrays, data-structures

```
String[] lac1 = {"1", "101", "1101"};
String[] lac2 = {"2", "102", "1102"};
String[] lac3 = {"3", "103", "1103","8", "108", "1108"};
```

I would like to search for a value in above arrays and get the array name of the array list in which the value is found.

e.g. 
if I am searching for lets say value 102, it should look into all the above arrays and get back the array name once found in any of the above array list.

Or, if you could help me with best datastructure for the above case.

Comment: use arraylist instead of array and use `contains()` method to check whether string is in list or not

Comment: Why dont you try yourself first

Answer (score 1):

if you have just use three array means just use if condition

```
String arraname="";
if (Arrays.asList(lac1).contains("102")) {
arraname="lac1";
 }
if (Arrays.asList(lac2).contains("102")) {
arraname="lac2";
 }
if (Arrays.asList(lac3).contains("102")) {
 arraname="lac3";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best data structure to solve the problem is using dictionary.
in java:

```
Map<int, String> dictionary = new HashMap<int, String>();
//put the data in..

//check existence
string value = map.get(key);
if (value != null) {
   ...
} else {
   // No such key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better data structure to store these details i will suggest a `Map` with key as `String` and value as `List<String>`

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

map.put("lac1",lac1List);
map.put("lac2",lac2List);
map.put("lac3",lac3List);
```

You can iterate the map and find the desired key.

```
String val; // value to be search
for(Entry<String,List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()){
    if(entry.value().contains(val)){
        System.out.println(val+" Present in "+entry.key());
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For array, you could try just `for` loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] lac1 = {"1", "101", "1101"};
    String[] lac2 = {"2", "102", "1102"};
    String[] lac3 = {"3", "103", "1103","8", "108", "1108"};
    int pos = -1;
    if ((pos = getPostion(lac1, "102")) > -1) {
        System.out.println("array lac1 , pos:" + pos);
    } else if ((pos = getPostion(lac2, "102")) > -1) {
        System.out.println("array lac2 , pos:" + pos);
    } else if ((pos = getPostion(lac3, "102")) > -1) {
        System.out.println("array lac3 , pos:" + pos);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Found!");
    }   
}

public static int getPostion(String[] arr, String key) {
    int pos = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].equals(key)) {
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array lac2 , pos:1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String checkValueInList(String val){
    String arrayName = "";
    String[] lac1 = {"1", "101", "1101"};
    String[] lac2 = {"2", "102", "1102"};
    String[] lac3 = {"3", "103", "1103","8", "108", "1108"};

    List<String> list1 = getArrayList();
    list1.add("lac1");
    List<String> list2 = getArrayList();
    list2.add("lac2");
    List<String> list3 = getArrayList();
    list3.add("lac3");

    list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(lac1));
    list2.addAll(Arrays.asList(lac2));
    list3.addAll(Arrays.asList(lac3));

    List<List<String>> allLists = new ArrayList<>();
    allLists.add(list1);
    allLists.add(list2);
    allLists.add(list3);

    for(List<String> stringList : allLists){
        if(stringList.contains(val)){
            arrayName = stringList.get(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    return arrayName;
}
```

Provide with more details like how do get data in arrays is it hardcoded or getting it from database? helps in choosing better collection. Instead of Lists inside List you can create a map with key value pair and return key value. You can try that!

Comment: The data in arrays are hard coded. 
I used Map for this. thank you.

Comment: @Megamind if you think this answer has helped you you can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

A Simple way could be:

```
public class mapList {
    Map<String,String> map;
    String[] lac1 = {"1", "101", "1101"};
    String[] lac2 = {"2", "102", "1102"};
    String[] lac3 = {"3", "103", "1103","8", "108", "1108"};

    public mapList(){  
        map = new HashMap<>();
        for(String l1:lac1){ map.put(l1, "lac1"); }
        for(String l2:lac2){ map.put(l2, "lac2"); }
        for(String l3:lac3){ map.put(l3, "lac3"); }        
    }

    public String search(String val){
        return map.get(val);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       mapList d=new mapList();
       System.out.println("1102 is in: " + d.search("1102"));
       System.out.println("8 is in: " + d.search("8"));
       System.out.println("101 is in: " + d.search("101"));
       System.out.println("1108 is in: " + d.search("1108"));
   }
}
```

The result:
    **1102** is in **lac2**;
    **8** is in **lac3**;
    **101** is in **lac1**;
    **1108** is in **lac3**;